# Node: route try to send response two times - ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set'); error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've got an API endpoint where user can specify id of the collection he wants to delete. Router read a json file, iterate through collections and delete found record:

```
router.delete('/todos/:id', (req,res)=>{
    const id = req.params.id
    fs.readFile('todos.json', 'utf8', (err,data) =>{
        if (err) throw err
        const JSONdata = JSON.parse(data)

        JSONdata.todos.forEach((todo, index)=>{
            if(todo.id == id){
                JSONdata.todos.splice(index,1)
                fs.writeFile('todos.json',JSON.stringify(JSONdata), 'utf8', (err) =>{
                    if (err) throw err
                    return res.json({"deleted" : true})
                })
            }
        })
    })
    res.status(404).json({errors: ['task not found']})
})
```

However instead of proper response {"deleted": true} I get this error:

> Server is running on port 3000
>   _http_outgoing.js:470
>       throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
>       ^
>
> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADER

I know this is related to the asynchronous nature of the node. But I was sure that adding return keyword if loop found a specific record will make it work. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fs.readFile is an Async function, it means that in your code, the

> res.status(404).json({errors: ['task not found']})

will be run first, and then the callback inside the fs.readFile function.

If you want to use a synchronic function, use fs.readFileSync.

You can read more about it here https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback

Answer (score 3):

Jest a litle change:

```
router.delete('/todos/:id', (req,res)=>{
    const id = req.params.id
    fs.readFile('todos.json', 'utf8', (err,data) =>{
        if (err) throw err
        const JSONdata = JSON.parse(data)

        JSONdata.todos.forEach((todo, index)=>{
            if(todo.id == id){
                JSONdata.todos.splice(index,1)
                fs.writeFile('todos.json',JSON.stringify(JSONdata), 'utf8', (err) =>{
                    if (err) throw err
                    return res.json({"deleted" : true})
                })
            }
        })
        return res.status(404).json({errors: ['task not found']})
    })
})
```